# Different encoding for arm64 "add x1, sp, x2, lsl #1" than with xzr

Tags: assembly, arm64, instruction-set, instruction-encoding

The `add x1, sp, x2, lsl #1` instruction is supposed to be an "Add (shifted register)" but I have problems with the encoding to differentiate when SP and XZR is used. I'm astonished with the results.

This is the encoding for the "ADD (shifted register)":

```
31:1, 30:0, 29:0, 28:0, 27:1, 26:0, 25:1, 24:1, 23..22:shift, 21:0, 20..16:Rm, 15..10:imm6, 9..5:Rn, 4..0:Rd
```

If I assemble `add x1, xzr, x2, lsl #1`, it matches the above encoding. Just to remark important bits:

```
E1 07 02 8B     add x1, xzr, x2, lsl #1

bit 21 = 0; 
shift = 0 (lsl); 
imm6 = 1
```

But if I assemble `add x1, sp, x2, lsl #1`, there are strange changes in the encoding. The changes are:

```
E1 67 22 8B     add x1, sp, x2, lsl #1

bit 21 = 1; 
shift = 0;
imm6 = 011001  (lsl 25)
```

So, I guess that bit 21 means SP instead of XZR. But why imm6 = 25? That's a "lsl 25"!

Am I looking at the wrong instruction encoding?

Comment: The thing that might be confusing is that there are two forms defined, which are called "ADD (shifted register)" and "ADD (extended register)".  However, the "extended register" version *also* can shift its operand, just not in such flexible ways (only left shift, and only by 0-4 bits).  And it doesn't necessarily have to do sign- or zero-extension.  So despite the fact that `add x1, sp, x2, lsl #1` applies a shift, and does not apply any extension, it is still a valid instance of the "ADD (extended register)" instruction.  But I can see why you wouldn't think to look there!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instruction encoded changes from “ADD (shifted register)” (§ C6.2.5) to “ADD (extended register)” (§ C6.2.3) if you use `SP` in an operand.  This is necessary as only the latter supports using `SP` or `WSP` in its first or second operands.

> I have problems with the encoding to differentiate when SP and XZR is used.

The instruction says which one of the two is used.  If `SP` is used, the field says something like `<Xn|SP>` and the text says “general-purpose register or stack pointer.”  When `XZR` is used, the field says something like `<Xn>` and the text just says “general-purpose register.”  You need to know which instruction you are decoding to know whether to decode `XZR` or `SP`.  And note that there are some times multiple instructions sharing the same mnemonic.  For example, the `ADD` mnemonic is shared by these (ignoring different operand sizes available for the same instruction):

```
ADD <Xd|SP>, <Xn|SP>, <R><m>{, <extend> {#<amount>}}
ADD <Xd|SP>, <Xn|SP>, #imm{, <shift>}
ADD <Xd>, <Xn>, <Xm>{, <shift> #<amount>}
ADD <V><d>, <V><n>, <V><m>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Everything is clear now. I missed also that important part in the description where SP is also specified in the instruction encoding (such as <Xd|SP>